# Why must the lock() function be used with a std::weak_ptr to safely extract the std::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, weak-ptr

Here's an example which shows two different ways of getting a shared_ptr from a weak_ptr:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

void print_shared1(std::weak_ptr <int> wp)
{
    // always gets pointer safely
    std::shared_ptr <int> sp(wp.lock());
    std::cout << "wp = " << (sp ? *sp : 0) << std::endl;
}

void print_shared2(std::weak_ptr <int> wp)
{
    // can crash if pointer has been freed
    std::shared_ptr <int> sp(wp);
    std::cout << "wp = " << (sp ? *sp : 0) << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    std::shared_ptr <int> s = std::make_shared<int>(1);
    std::weak_ptr <int> w = s;

    print_shared1(w);
    print_shared2(w);

    s.reset();
    
    print_shared1(w);
    print_shared2(w);
}
```

When it is run, this is the output:

```
wp = 1
wp = 1
wp = 0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
  what():  bad_weak_ptr
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Clearly it is not always safe to access a weak pointer simply by constructing a shared pointer from it.

My questions are:

1. In the function print_shared2, why are the semantics of wp.lock() not used during the construction of sp?
2. Of what use is std::bad_weak_ptr at all?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: He asked about the exception, not `weak_ptr` in general.

Comment: @NicolBolas ah, right you are.  I missed that detail.

Answer (score 3):

> Of what use is std::bad_weak_ptr at all?

You just *saw* the use of it. `lock` returns an empty `shared_ptr`; the constructor throws an exception.

Using the `shared_ptr` constructor means "I am certain that this `weak_ptr` is valid, and if it isn't, that is an exceptional error condition that must be handled immediately." If you are uncertain of the status of the `weak_ptr` and want to check it, use `lock`.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is the constructor [`std::shared_ptr<Y>::shared_ptr(const std::weak_ptr<Y>& r) (11)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) that allows doing it.
2. While constructing a shared pointer it checks `if (sp)`.

   > Note that `r.lock()` may be used for the same purpose: the difference is that this constructor throws an exception if the argument is empty, while `std::weak_ptr<T>::lock()` constructs an empty `std::shared_ptr` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Because that's how that `std::shared_ptr` constructor works.  From [[util.smartptr.shared.const]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/util.smartptr.shared.const):

> `template<class Y> explicit shared_ptr(const weak_ptr<Y>& r);`
>     *Constraints*: `Y*` is compatible with `T*`.
>     *Effects*: Constructs a `shared_­ptr` object that shares ownership with `r` and stores a copy of the pointer stored in `r`. If an exception is thrown, the constructor has no effect.
>     *Postconditions*: `use_­count() == r.use_­count()`.
>     *Throws*: `bad_­weak_­ptr` when `r.expired()`.

---

Why?  Because that's the the semantics that the standard authors decided to give it.  If you attempt to construct a `std::shared_ptr` directly from a `std::weak_ptr` then you are asserting that the `weak_ptr` is valid.  If you're not sure, use `lock`.